# How to test a user has a managed policy using CDK assertions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've defined a user and a managed policy in CDK v2, similar to:

```js
    const policy = new iam.ManagedPolicy(this, `s3access`, {
      statements: [
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
          effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
          actions: ['s3:PutObject', 's3:GetObject'],
          resources: ['*']
        })
      ]
    })
  
    const someUser = new iam.User(this, 'some-user', { managedPolicies: [policy] });
```

I want to test that the user has the managed policy applied to it using CDK test assertions, however I'm struggling to figure out how using the existing test constructs:

```js
    template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy', {
      PolicyDocument: Match.objectLike({
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: ['s3:PutObject', 's3:GetObject'],
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Resource: [
              '*'
            ]
          },
        ]
      })
    })
```

...matches the managed policy, but doesn't test that the user has the managed policy applied.

What is the pattern / best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the User's Managed Policy Arn as it appears in the template:

```json
"Type": "AWS::IAM::User",
"Properties": {
"ManagedPolicyArns": [
  {
  "Ref": "s3access10922181"
  }
]
```

The trick is to get the `{"Ref": "s3access10922181"}` reference to the policy. Here are two equivalent approaches:

##### Approach 1: `stack.node.tryFindChild`

```js
const managedPolicyChild = stack.node.tryFindChild('s3access') as iam.ManagedPolicy | undefined;
if (!managedPolicyChild) throw new Error('Expected a defined ManagedPolicy');

const policyArnRef = stack.resolve(managedPolicyChild.managedPolicyArn);

template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::IAM::User', {
  ManagedPolicyArns: Match.arrayWith([policyArnRef]),
});
```

##### Approach 2: `template.findResources`

```js
const managedPolicyResources = template.findResources('AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy');
const managedPolicyLogicalId = Object.keys(managedPolicyResources).find((k) => k.startsWith('s3access'));
if (!managedPolicyLogicalId) throw new Error('Expected to find a ManagedPolicy Id');

template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::IAM::User', {
  ManagedPolicyArns: Match.arrayWith([{ Ref: managedPolicyLogicalId }]),
});
```